# Golang websocket wont connect

Tags: go, websocket, chat, go-fiber

[image]

I got that error while connecting to my golang websocket

this is my route setup in route.go

```
func Setup(app *fiber.App) {
app.Use(cache.New(cache.Config{
        Next: func(c *fiber.Ctx) bool {
            return strings.Contains(c.Route().Path, "/chat/ws")
        },
    }))
    admin_route.Get("/chat/ws", websocket.New(admin.WebsocketChat))

    go admin.SocketManager()
}
```

this is the admin.websocketchat and admin.socketmanager that being called inside the route.go

```
var (
    register   = make(chan *websocket.Conn)
    unregister = make(chan *websocket.Conn)
    clients    = make(map[*websocket.Conn]bool)
)
func SocketListener(c *websocket.Conn) {
    // Handle incoming messages from WebSocket connection
    for {
        messageType, message, err := c.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            if websocket.IsUnexpectedCloseError(err, websocket.CloseGoingAway, websocket.CloseAbnormalClosure) {
                log.Println("read error:", err)
            }
            return
        }
        if messageType == websocket.TextMessage {
            log.Println("got text message:", string(message))

            // Broadcast the message to all connected clients
            for client := range clients {
                err := client.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, message)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Println("error writing message:", err)
                    return
                }
            }
        } else {
            log.Println("received message of type:", messageType)
        }
    }
}

func WebsocketChat(c *websocket.Conn) {
    register <- c
    defer func() {
        unregister <- c
        c.Close()
    }()
    go SocketListener(c)
}

func SocketManager() {
    for {
        select {
        case c := <-register:
            clients[c] = true
        case c := <-unregister:
            delete(clients, c)
        }
    }
}
```

I dont know what's wrong with this code, and there's not much of forum on this kinda question

Comment: Where in Go code do you set up your socket listener to listen on port 3000?